# How to make a by-language title both in boldface?

Tags: titles, titling

[image: title result]
As shown in the figure below, I try to make the title all covered in bold face, but after trying to use \textbf with the specific character I want, I still get a medium series in English. Is there any way to adjust that, and why is this happening?

My code are pasted here, and thx so much!

```
\documentclass[UTF8,notitlepage]{ctexart}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{titling}

\pretitle{\begin{center}\huge\songti\bfseries} %二号宋粗体
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 10.5pt} %空一行五号
\preauthor{
\begin{center} \lineskip 0.5em
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}} %垂直对齐
\large\songti 
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\par
\end{center}}
\newcommand{\address}{\begin{center}
\normalsize\songti
\end{center}}


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%SETTING OF TITLE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{C7\quad 基于空间光调制器(SLM)的光学实验} %中文题目
\author{何锦环 \and 杨雪滢} %中文作者
\address{（物理学院物理学系，广东省广州市，510275）} %中文单位
\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% END OF TITLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the English font *has* a bold face. If the non-English font is going into bold, that is the most likely problem.

Comment: @PaulStanley is right, if you remove `\usepackage{times}` then another font is used which correctly renders in bold.

Answer (score 1):

The package `times` does not work properly with `xelatex` or `lualatex` (however with `pdflatex` there is no problem).

You can remove the package, or if you want a Times-based font you can use TeX Gyre Termes with the `newtxtext` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[UTF8,notitlepage]{ctexart}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{titling}

\pretitle{\begin{center}\huge\songti\bfseries} %二号宋粗体
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 10.5pt} %空一行五号
\preauthor{
\begin{center} \lineskip 0.5em
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}} %垂直对齐
\large\songti 
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\par
\end{center}}
\newcommand{\address}{\begin{center}
\normalsize\songti
\end{center}}


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%SETTING OF TITLE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{C7\quad 基于空间光调制器(SLM)的光学实验} %中文题目
\author{何锦环 \and 杨雪滢} %中文作者
\address{（物理学院物理学系，广东省广州市，510275）} %中文单位
\maketitle

TeX Gyre Termes looks like Times New Roman \textbf{and has bold}.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% END OF TITLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]